# Manually Setting dirty to a field does not modifies the css classes angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a form using angular js. On form submit, I am setting the fields to dirty if they are not valid. But the problem is even after setting the fields to dirty it does not changes the CSS property on the field. `ng-pristine` class still remains on those elements.It does not changes the class to `ng-dirty` after setting the field to dirty.

After submitting the form you can see the error messages, but it is not applying the `ng-dirty` css class.

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

sampleApp.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.userData = {

      fname: "",
      lname: ""
    };


    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submitForm = function(registrationForm) {
      $scope.registrationForm.fname.$dirty = true;
   $scope.registrationForm.lname.$dirty = true;
      if (registrationForm.$invalid) {
        alert("form validation error.");
        return;
      } else {
        alert("form submitted successfully.");
      }

    }
  }
]);
```

```css
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
input.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input.ng-pristine { 
  border-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">

<body ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
  <form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="submitForm(registrationForm)" novalidate>
    First Name*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="userData.fname" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span ng-show="registrationForm.fname.$dirty && registrationForm.fname.$error.required">
    First name is required.
   </span>

    <br>Last Name*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="userData.lname" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span ng-show="registrationForm.lname.$dirty && registrationForm.lname.$error.required">
    Last name is required.
   </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI: I know i can disable the submit button, but I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

`$scope.registrationForm.lname.$dirty`

with

`$scope.registrationForm.lname.$setDirty();`

> $setDirty();
>
> Sets the form to a dirty state.
>
> This method can be called to add the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form
>   to a dirty state (ng-dirty class). This method will also propagate to
>   parent forms.

[AngularJS Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#!)

Comment: @user3427540 you should accept the answer indeed :)